# Can't install Microsoft Office 2013 update

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, microsoft-office-2013

I had installed Office 2013 on May 4, and an update appeared for it in Windows Update May 5. I tried to install it, but when windows update  got to office 2013 update, it stops giving me an error message.

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit, Office 2013 64 bit.

The update I'm trying to install is this: Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2768349) 64-Bit Edition

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this error.  Look at the following [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/failed-update-for-office-2013-x64-kb2768349-via/b8c2d7a3-c0db-4852-9da6-90318b7cc411).

Comment: Link-only answers are a no no on SU due to possible future link-rot. Please include pertinent information in your answer. :)